# Using docker entrypoint and files outside docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I'm writing a python script which to create AWS CloudFormation change-sets to simplify the execution I want to add this script to a Docker image and run it as the entrypoint.

To achieve that, I have to read the CFs template file and parameters file, both are in json format. 
When I execute the script on the local shell environment everything works as expected.

When I run the docker container and specify the files. The script says that it could not find the file.

Now my question is how can I enable the container getting access to this files?

```sh
docker pull cf-create-change-set:latest
docker run cf-create-change-set:latest --template-body ./template.json --cli-input-json ./parameters.json

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/cf-create-change-set.py", line 266, in <module>
    with open(CLI_INPUT_JSON, 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './template.json'
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com/cicd/docker-base-image:iat

WORKDIR /app

# Copy app data
COPY app/requirements.txt .
COPY app/cf-create-change-set.py .

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/cf-create-change-set.py" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the file does not exist inside the container while it exists in your filesystem. There are at least two possible solutions.

You can either `ADD` the files into the container at build stage (build your own Dockerfile) or map a local directory to a directory inside the container:

```
docker run -v ./templates:/templates image:tag --template-body /templates/template.json
```

This way when you run the container it will have the same file located at `/templates/template.json` as the contents of your local `templates` folder. Read more about [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

Comment: Hello @YuryFedorov yes this is possible and I know that feature. The problem ist, that I do have to type each time I want to use my cmdline feature a lot of lines. Do you have any other recommendations? Maybe reading form the STDIN or something like that?